# How to display $variables in drupal 6 preprocess function?

Tags: hooks

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out what variables are within the scope of my `hook_preprocess` function.  I even tried to `print_r($variables['fields'])`, but I keep getting this long recursive mess.  Is there a much easier way in drupal 6 to see what values I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel).

Once installed use the function `dpm()` like this: `dpm($variables);`

This will give you a nice print out of your variables.